# How do I check if a date is between two ranges (ReactJS/JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

So Lets say I have the date(IN THIS EXACT STRING FORMAT)

```
2017-4-28
```

and the dates

```
2017-4-20
2017-5-16
```

How would I check to see if the first one is between the two?

EDIT: THESE ARE BOTH STRINGS

Comment: you can use `moment.js` or `javascript date object`.

Comment: @Adriani6 You can actually use `<` and `>` against `Date` objects directly, not need to `getTime()`

Comment: @samanime Never knew, thanks for that. We learn something new every day ;)

Comment: Clearly no attempt was made to research this before asking. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+much+research)

Comment: Given the string format, it's simpler in this case to use [*localeCompare*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and avoid Date objects, e.g.: `if (a.localeCompare(b) < 0)` then a is before b. It is very likely that "2017-4-20" will be treated as an invalid date by some built-in parsers, but not by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const date = new Date('2017-4-28');
const start = new Date('2017-4-20');
const end = new Date('2017-5-16');

if (date > start && date < end) {
  console.log('in between');
} else {
  console.log('outside');
}
```

As with most things involving dates, it's best to convert them to `Date` objects. The format you're using is one that it can parse directly, so that's easy, just `new Date(dateStr)`.

After that, it's easy to compare them. The `<` and `>` operators work on `Date` objects just as you expect they would, so you can just check `date > start` and `date < end`.

Comment: "*As with most things involving dates…*" In this case, it's simpler to just compare the strings using [*localeCompare*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), there's no need to resort to using the built-in parser (which is notoriously unreliable).

Comment: Actually, with this exact format that wouldn't work, because '2017-12-01' would be indicated as before '2017-2-01', since they aren't using a two-digit month in all cases. And while I agree the parser can be finicky, I'd say the vast majority of browsers at least get the `YYYY-MM-DD` format correct.

Comment: Yes, you're correct about the *localCompare*, I missed the malformed string. It's not about "the vast majority", the string is not valid ISO 8601 so browsers can either attempt to parse it as something else or return an invalid date. It's a lottery as to which result you'll get, including whether it's parsed as UTC or local (which I guess doesn't matter for comparison but may in other cases).